# How to calculate cumulative sum in PHP?

Tags: php, html, string, for-loop, html-table

I want to calculate the sum and output a two columns table. But, the format is wrong. The numbers are all packed in one line.

[image: Wrong table]

```
 <td>
 <?php
for ($j = 1; $j <= 10; $j++)
    {
        print "<tr>";
        print $j;
        print "</tr>";
    }
?>    
 </td>

 <td>
 <?php
$sum = 0;
for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++) 
{
     print "<tr>";
     print $sum = $sum + $i;
     print "</tr>";

}
?>    
 </td>
```

Comment: `<tr>` is a row `<td>` should be a cell. Do you have a table?

Comment: switch the trs and tds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we would be writing one or two for loops, join our desired `HTML` string, and finally we would print it.

#### Test:

```
<?php

$html = '<tr>';

for ($j = 1; $j <= 10; $j++) {
    $html .= "<td>" . $j . "</td>";
}

$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '<tr>';

$sum = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $sum += $i;
    $html .= "<td>" . $sum . "</td>";
}

$html .= '</tr>';

print($html);

?>
```

We would be also adding table open and close tags (`<table>`, `</table>`):

```
<?php

$html = '<table>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= "<td>Number</td>";

for ($j = 1; $j <= 10; $j++) {
    $html .= "<td>" . $j . "</td>";
}

$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= "<td>Cumulative Sum</td>";
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $sum += $i;
    $html .= "<td>" . $sum . "</td>";
}

$html .= '</tr>';
$html .= '</table>';

print($html);

?>
```

[image: Two rows]

For two columns, we would just use one for` loop:

```
<?php

$html = '<table>';
$html .= "<tr><th>Number</th><th>Cumulative Sum</th></tr>";

for ($j = 1; $j <= 10; $j++) {
    $html .= "<tr>";
        $html .= "<th>" . $j . "</th>";
        $sum += $j;
        $html .= "<th>" . $sum . "</th>";
    $html .= "</tr>";
}

$html .= '</table>';

print($html);
```

[image: Two Col]

Comment: But the results are two rows. How to output two columns?

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here when looking to get a cumulative sum in PHP. For the ones like me, I wrote the following function. It's safe for empty arrays as well.

```php
function cumsum ($arr) {
    return array_reduce($arr, function ($c, $i) { $c[] = end($c) + $i; return $c; }, []);
}
```